# WordPress Authenticate filter runs multiple times

Tags: wordpress, authentication, filter

I'm currently trying to override Wordpress `wp_authenticate function` by using the Authenticate filter, everything seems perfect but the functions always run multiple times.

```
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'myplugin_auth_signon', 30, 3 );
function myplugin_auth_signon( $user, $username, $password ) {

if(isset($_POST['wp-submit'])){

        $creds                  = array();
        $creds['user_login']    = $_POST['log'];
        $creds['user_password'] = $_POST['pwd'];
        $creds['remember']      = true;

    $my_error = new WP_Error();
    $userid =   get_user_by( 'login', $_POST['log'] );
    echo $userid = $userid->ID;
    $meta = get_usermeta( $userid, 'is_active' );
    if($meta == '0'){
        echo "please verify account first |||||";
        return 0;
    }else{

         return $user;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: ***functions always run multiple times.*** means ? you mean `echo "please verify account first |||||";` runs multiple times ?

Comment: yes it always run more than 1 time

Comment: I think it has something to do with `return 0`. can you try `return false` ?